# Converting Script from Powershell to Python-Regex Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert a Powershell Script to a python script.  I was going to use a Shell script for the ease of use for grep and curl, but I decided on python for the ease of if statements.
This is the Powershell code that I am trying to convert:

Powershell code (works great):

```
$ReturnedRegExData = SearchStringAll -StringToSearch $Data -RegEx $ImgURLRegex 

if ($ReturnedRegExData) #Check Existance of Matches
{
    foreach ($Image in $ReturnedRegExImageData) #Run Through all Matches
    #Can then get the result from the group of results and run through them 1 at a time via $Image
}
else
{
    #exit
}
```

This is my attempt at Python, not working too good

```
ReturnedRegExData = re.findall($ImgURLRegex , $Data)

if ReturnedRegExImageData: #Check existance of Matches (Works)
    print "found"
else:
    sys.stderr.write("Error finding Regex \r\n")
    return

$For Loop running through results
```

re.search worked with this print ReturnedRegExImageData.group(0), but I want to find all matches, and having an extremely hard time replicating foreach ($Image in $ReturnedRegExImageData) this line:
I've tried messing around with for Image in ReturnedRegExData and a for loop from 0 to len(ReturnedRegExData), but they don't return valid data.  I know Python is supposed to be simple coding, but I am having an extremely hard time of dealing with it.

I've read similar posts for .match, /search and .findall, and they all go over the searching part, but nothing goes over how to get the results in a useful format.  I have looked through the manual, but I'm having a hard time deciphering that as well.

How can I run through the results that findall found, whether returns 0, 1 or more results.  0 Should be covered by the if statement.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

J

Comment: What is your regular expression? What is your sample data? What are you currently getting for output?

Comment: And, can you post some actual Python code? (Python doesn't use `$` in front of variable names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findall` function returns a list of strings. So you can do something like:

```
found = re.findall(img_url_regex, data)
if not found: # the list is empty
    sys.stderr.write("Error finding Regex \r\n")
else:
    for imgurl in found:
        print 'Found image:', imgurl
        # whatever else you want to do with the URL.
```

Note that using $ to start variable names is not valid python;

```
In [3]: $foo = 12
  File "<ipython-input-3-38be62380e9f>", line 1
    $foo = 12
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you want to replace parts of the found URLs, you can use `sub()` method. It uses the [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject). Below is an example from one of my own scripts. I use it to change e.g. `<img alt='pic' class="align-left" src="static/test.jpg" />` to `<img alt='pic' class="align-left" src="static/images/test.jpg" />`

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
# fix image links
img = re.compile(r'src="[\./]*static/([^"]*)"')
data = img.sub(lambda m: (r'src="' + prefix + 'static/images/' + 
                          m.group(1) + r'"'), data)
with open(filename, 'w+') as of:
    of.write(data)
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I had a for Image in ReturnedRegExImageData: loop before, but for some reason with my testing this morning, it wasn't working, but it is working now.  Thank you very much!